# How to change cell background color of particular cell in agendaWeek view in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way change cell background color of particular cell in agendaWeek view, when the  calendar is first loaded.

Ex Tuesday 9:00 am to 9:30am slot should be colored green

Comment: From Review: Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54399175/edit) your question and provide some sample code for others to start with?

Comment: that slot is empty or contain an event? you want to color the slot or the event?

Comment: I want to color a empty slot with one color, and the ones with events another color .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add an background event on the desired timeslot every tuesday and then set that event's color to green.

- [Background Events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events)
- [Event Color](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventColor)

Alternatively you could check out the [Business hours functionality](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours)